# Regex matching line not containing the string

Tags: regex

I'd like to select a lines with does not contain a word SCREEN. I tried the following regex `(?<!SCREEN).+` but it seems not to work - selects all the lines. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The `.+` will match anything (that is at least 1 character long), so it effectively cancels your negative lookbehind. Check this solution out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Answer (score 48):

The short answer: `^((?!SCREEN).)*$`

This is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word which contains a full explanation

Comment: I think `^(?:(?!SCREEN).)*$` would be more efficient

Answer (score -3):

Another try for this case: (SCREEN){0}.*$

Hope that can help.

Comment: This still matches lines with "SCREEN" too. https://regex101.com/r/CyaPYl/1